# Unusual hash map implementation

Tags: hash, hashtable

Does anyone know the original hash table implementation?

Every realization I've found is based on separate chaining or open addressing methods

Comment: What do you mean by original? Original in what context?

Answer (score 0):

Chaining, by Hans Peter Luhn, in 1953.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#History

Comment: This is a link-only answer at this point. It needs to include at least a summary of the content at the link.

Answer (score 0):

The first implementation, not that the most common, is probably the one that uses an array (which is resized as needed) where each entry points to a list of elements.

The hash code, computed mod the size of the array, points to the integer index at which the list of the element to be searched is located. In case of hash code collision, the elements will accumulate in the list of the related entry.

So, once the hash code is computed, we have O(1) for accessing the entry of the array and O(N) for the actual search of the element in the list by verifying its actual equality. The value of N must be kept low for obvious performance consequences.

In case the collision becomes high we resize the array by increasing the number of entries and decreasing the collisions accordingly. This occurs as the hash code mod a higher number than the previous one is computed.

Some more complicated implementations convert the lists to trees if they become too long so that O(N) to O(log(N)) for equality search.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).